# How can I start an illager raid via commands?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How can I start an illager raid via commands? I've looked into mob events but they don't seem to trigger anything.

I'd prefer a solution where it not be required that the player is in a village for it to start.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you *have* to be in a village to participate in a raid. Fortunately though, you can create your own village by only having 1 villager next to or near it's linked bed. You can check to see if it is linked to a bed by checking to see if it sleeps in said bed at night. Once you do this, simply use this command and the raid will start.

`/effect @s bad_omen`

Just note that if the villager is killed at any point between the start and end of the raid, the raid will be counted as a defeat.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be an unused /raid command which manages raids. Not sure why it was not added to the game.

https://tcrf.net/Minecraft:_Java_Edition#raid

Answer (score -1):

try this works on 1.16 (Java)

```
/effect give @s minecraft:bad_omen
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Arqade! If you could please complete the answer to tell us how this answer is different and needed to complete the answer from @Banana97286 ? Is the give part of the command needed above or below a particular version?

Answer (score -2):

The command is:

```
/summon pillager ~ ~ ~ minecraft:spawn_as_illager_captain
```

The three tildes (`~`) means it will be summoned at your exact location. you can change this by replacing it with coordinates with a space in between:

```
/summon pillager 100 65 -57 minecraft:spawn_as_illager_captain
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: That seems like it will just summon an illager capital, not start a raid.

Comment: /effect <username here> minecraft:bad_omen is the command, however you need a village for it to summon the raid

Comment: I have thought about this. But this only gives you the bad omen effect which, indeed summons a raid when you enter a village structure area, but if you want to ummon a raid anywhere in the world, without the bad omen effect, you will need other commands. Also,  this is the equivalent of getting a bad omen effect from any nearby outpost... It all depends on the intention...

Comment: Yes I tried this when I was looking at mob events but all it did was spawn the captain and nothing else

Comment: @Geekdeserpentard.D “you will need other commands” could you point me to what you mean?

Answer (score -2):

To start a raid, use this command in the chat, and you will get the Bad Omen effect. To make a raid happen, just walk into a village in survival mode for it to start.

```
/effect @s bad_omen
```